# right click select program to open the file

Tags: mouse, system-settings

I would like to select the program to open the file.
I use right click, Ubuntu automatically open the file using default program.
For example, I want to to use gedit to open .pas file. Ubuntu does not give me a chance to select, but open Lazarus to open it.

I go to system setting and adjust mouse double click speed, but no matter what I adjust, it keeps the same to open Lazarus.

I would like to know are there any place to adjust the speed for right click to let me select the program to open the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Right click the file in question, and click "Properties".

[image: Properties dialog]

**2)** In the properties window, select the "Open with" tab.  Highlight the program you want to open those types of files with and select "Set as Default".
[image: Default app]

**3)** Now focus your file browser window, click the "Edit" menu, then "Preferences".
[image: Preferences]

**4)** Go to the "Behavior" tab, and under the heading "Executable text files" select the option "Ask each time".  That way it won't default to one specific type of behavior with certain files, it will just ask.
[image: Behavior]